# Hide a folder but allow access to its contents

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

Is it possible to hide a specific folder from a group but still allow that group to access the files when given a direct link?

Answer (score 0):

We can not hide the folder but can restrict the permission. Stop inheriting the permission folder, and add unique permission to the item (file) not in the folder while sharing with other user.

For details about the permission in files and folders refer to the below article :

[In my SharePoint My Site, how can I share documents with only specific people?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/bbmp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

1. Remove group permission on the specific folder.

Choose the folder->shared with->Advanced->Remove the group permission.

2. Set unique permission on files and grant group permission on the files.

Choose the file->shared with->Advanced->Stop Inheriting Permissions->then grant the group permission.